# apache mod_rewrite : how to add url rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to rediect http://example.com/about to http://example.com/about-us using apache mod_rewrite ?

I wrote the following code in .htaccess file. But I get too many redirects error.

```
#RewriteRule about    http://example.com/about-us [R=301,L]
```

Help me in finding a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Regular expression `^about$` does not match `about-us`.):

```
RewriteRule ^about$    http://example.com/about-us [R=301,L]
```

In this case, you can use `RedirectMatch` directive instead.